# Beginning jbpm 6 questions about expectations of integration

Tags: deployment, jbpm, kie, kie-wb

I have been researching the jbpm / drools engine and have been working on a proof of concept using jbpm 6 and the kie workbench.  I am currently working on a proof of concept for page navigation, the process  should receive a variable representing an action the user took on the page the engine uses the variable in the process to decide which page will be displayed to the user next and returns that value.

I have created this navigation example in drools and jbpm that has the "user action" variable mapped as a parameter before starting the process. Both a drools and jbpm application are created through eclipse where the process operated off a JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase class with console printouts that show me both processes are working as I expect.

Now I am working with the Kie Workbench in an effort to construct the same projects but produce a jar file that can be consumed by a stand alone application. Currently I am having trouble finding information for some questions and I not sure if my expectations are exceeding what Kie Workbench was designed to do.

Overall I would like to have a resulting jar file deployed from Kie Workbench that can be used in a stand alone application.  It will use a data object from the data modeler that can be assigned values from the stand alone application.  I will then run the Business process from the stand alone application to get the return a result to work with and load the corresponding page.

I have accessed the data object included in the deployed jar, can that jar also contain a KB and Session I can attach the data object to and run the process? I would eventually like to see a jar file I can include in a web page where I can instantiate the data object class, assign values and then attach and run a session without adding any additional libraries to the stand alone application.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to create your project(s) with all the assets and data models, you can build and deploy the project and that will generate a maven artefact (jar) which will be installed in a local maven repo. You can consume that jar inside your stand alone application. if you are using maven in your standalone application, you just need to add the dependency to your project and the kie-wb repository and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, when it is referenced in my stand alone application am I able to access a pregenerated knowledgebase that I can design on the knowledge base settings or do I have to construct it from the jar? If the knowledge base setting do not create a knowledgebase how are they best used for deployment? I really appreciate your time, and I am still actively researching these questions.

Comment: Hi there, I don't fully understand your question, can you please elaborate on what are you planning to do? 
Most of the time, you will be generating jars with the KIE Workbench and consuming those jars in your standalone applications as normal dependencies. What do you mean by "I can design on the knowledge base settings" ? Regards